# Is it possible to control the values of non-color fields by looked-up?

Tags: java, css, javafx

## CSS

Main class **toggle-switch**:

```
.toggle-switch {
    radius: 16;

    thumb-area-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    thumb-area-border-width: 2;
    thumb-area-border-color: #d9d9d9;
}
```

And child class **thumb-area**:

```
.thumb-area {
    -fx-background-radius: radius;
    -fx-border-radius: radius;

    -fx-background-color: thumb-area-background-color;
    -fx-border-width: thumb-area-border-width;
    -fx-border-color: thumb-area-border-color;   
}
```

The fields **thumb-area-background-color** и **thumb-area-border-color**, responsible for the color, change perfectly from the code and are processed without errors:

```
toggleSwitch.setStyle("thumb-background-color: " + getRGBAString(color));
toggleSwitch.setStyle("thumb-area-background-color: " + getRGBAString(color));
```

But the fields **radius** и **thumb-area-border-width**, are not processed! When i start the program, the console displays:

```
WARNING: Caught 'java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to com.sun.javafx.css.Size' while converting value for '-fx-background-radius' from rule '*.thumb-area' in stylesheet file:/...
*date* javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue

WARNING: Caught 'java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to com.sun.javafx.css.Size' while converting value for '-fx-border-radius' from rule '*.thumb-area' in stylesheet file:/...
*date* javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue

WARNING: Caught 'java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to com.sun.javafx.css.Size' while converting value for '-fx-border-width' from rule '*.thumb-area' in stylesheet file:/...
*date* javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue
```

The path to the file and date are removed.

Is it possible to control the values ​​of non-color fields with **looked-up** or if there is no such option, how better to change these values ​​programmatically from code without overriding **css** fields (When used for example **setStyle** for **thumbArea** all values ​​from **css** class **thumb-area** are lost)

The way to make all fields programmatically by using **setStyle** **does not** fit.

Comment: if you change `radius: 16` to `radius: 16 16 16 16`, do you get the same error or a different one?

Comment: This does not help + in my example, I wrote that the error also occurs when trying to set the width.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `radius` is being stored as a Double instead of a Size, which is what `-fx-background-radius` is expecting. 
Try `radius: 16px;` and see if that works any better?